# how to determine overflow if c(n-2) is not accessible

Tags: cpu-architecture

given an n-bit 2's complement adder/subtractor what is the overflow logic. i don't have access to internal circuit design. Only 2 n-bit numbers, sum, add/sub, carry(in), carry(out)

Comment: Does [this discussion about unsigned carry vs. signed overflow help](http://teaching.idallen.com/dat2343/10f/notes/040_overflow.txt)?  There are some nice examples with 4-bit numbers for carry.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few rules for determining overflow in this case. (Note: this only applies to addition, but treating `A - B` as `A + (-B)`, you can figure out the rules for subtraction as well).

1. If the two inputs have different signs, then there's no possibility of overflow.
2. If they have the same sign, but the output has a different sign, then you have an overflow. For example, if you add two positive numbers but get a negative result, you know it's an overflow (since two positives can't sum to a negative).

In other words, `Overflow = (Sign(A) == Sign(B)) and (Sign(Sum) != Sign(A))`.

Comment: Do you mean carry(out) bit != sign(A) or lastBit(sum) != sign(A)?

Comment: @sayeed the sign of a number is just the most-significant bit (i.e. *not* the carry out).